# SQL Server - Multiple FROM keywords?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The search term is to ambiguous for google aparently. I am looking at a SQL call and it has 2 FROM keywords? I've never seen this before, can someone explain?

```
SELECT TOP(5)  SUM(column) AS column, column
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT column, column, column
FROM ((((((table table 
INNER JOIN table table ON (column = column
AND column = 2 
AND column != '' )) 
INNER JOIN table table ON (column   = column 
AND (column = 144 OR column = 159 OR column = 162 OR column = 164 OR column = 163 OR column  = 1 OR column = 2 OR column = 122 OR column = 155 OR column = 156 )))
inner join table table ON (column = column 
AND column  = 0 ))
INNER JOIN table  ON (column = column  ))
INNER JOIN table table ON ( column  = column  
AND (column   = 102 OR column  = 103 )))
INNER JOIN table table ON (column  = column  ))) TempTable  
GROUP BY column  ORDER BY column  desc
```

You will note the multiple FROM keywords. It runs just fine. Just curious to what the purpose is.

Comment: You're probably seeing a nested subquery.

Comment: I thought  you needed the UNION keyword to do that?

Comment: your ellipses prevent us from seeing the actual problem

Comment: Format your query by indenting subqueries and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: If you formatted the SQL you might see what's happening

Comment: So I know this is embarassing but I have no clue how to format SQL queries.... One day perhaps, but it's not today.

Comment: If you use real names for columns and tables it would be more readable.

Comment: @VahidND not going to happen cheif sorry.

Comment: I mean fake names would help too, but not naming every column a 'column' and every table as 'table'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called as `subquery`. You can use `subquery` within your main query 
So subquery made the multiple FORM clause.

Comment: I dont know why this got downvoted but an upvote would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

There's a reason why SQL is called a **Structured** Query Language: it lets you formulate queries that use other queries as their source, thus creating a hierarchical query structure.

This is a common practice: each `FROM` keyword is actually paired with its own `SELECT`, making the inner query a source for the outer one.

Proper formatting would help you understand what is going on: indenting inner `SELECT`s helps you see the structure of your query, making it easier to understand which part is used as the source of what other parts:

```
SELECT TOP(5)  SUM(price) AS total_price, item_id
FROM ( -- The output of this query serves as input for the outer query
     SELECT price, item
     FROM order -- This may have its own selects, joins, etc.
     GROUP BY order_id
)
GROUP BY item_id
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL supports `SELECT`ing from the results of another, nested `SELECT`. As already mentioned, the nested SELECT is called a subquery.

More details about subqueries and examples of their use in MSSQL Server can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx

Subquery used to select into an aliased column:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Ord.SalesOrderID, Ord.OrderDate,
    (SELECT MAX(OrdDet.UnitPrice)
     FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS OrdDet
     WHERE Ord.SalesOrderID = OrdDet.SalesOrderID) AS MaxUnitPrice
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Ord
```

Using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause (from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200127/SQL-Joins-and-Subqueries)

```
-- Use a Subquery
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address 
WHERE StateProvinceID IN
(
    SELECT StateProvinceID 
    FROM AdventureWorks.Person.StateProvince 
    WHERE StateProvinceCode = 'CA'
)
-- Use a Join
SELECT addr.* 
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address addr
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Person.StateProvince state 
ON addr.StateProvinceID = state.StateProvinceID
WHERE state.StateProvinceCode = 'CA'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing `FROM` clauses in subqueries.  If you tabify the query it may be more obvious

```
SELECT TOP(5)  SUM(column) AS column, column
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT column, column, column
    FROM ((((((table table 
    ...
    INNER JOIN table table ON (column  = column  ))) TempTable 
GROUP BY column  
ORDER BY column  desc
```

Comment: I dont know why this got downvoted but an upvote would be appreciated